# how I can tell subprocess.check_output to drop old content but only keep last N bytes?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

```
subprocess.check_output('command generate very large output > 2GBs/s')
```

The PIPE does not seems to have size limitation thus it blows up the RAM. I actually only need the last N bytes and want to drop the previous output.

One option will be read the stdout in a loop:

```
N = 5
with subprocess.Popen("dd if=/dev/zero bs=10M count=1000 && echo test", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as p:
    pre_block = b""
    while block:=p.stdout.read(int(100*1024**2)):
        if len(block) >= N:
            pre_block = block[-N:]
        else:
            pre_block = pre_block[-(N-len(block)):] + block
    print(pre_block)
```

However, the wile loop usually are too slow to keep up the speed. Also the read() and PIPE wasting RAM here. And we really want is not always read out the data but skip it.

One thoughts is to seek to the end of the file, however stdout is not seekable:

```
with subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=sbuprocess.PIPE) as p:
    with subprocess.Popen("dd if=/dev/zero bs=10M count=1000 && echo test", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as p:
    p.stdout.seek(-N, os.SEEK_END)
    print(file.read())
```

And even it is seekable, we are going to blow up the memory anyway.

Is there some byte IO object like a non-blocking fifo that I can use as stdout allow dropping old content quickly?

Answer (score 0):

*Unix-based* solution:

Pipe your main process with unix **`tail -c NUM`** command which will output the last `NUM` bytes from *stdin*.

```
n = 5
with subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) as p:
    with subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-c', str(n)], 
                          stdin=p.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as tail:
        last_chunk = tail.stdout.read()
        print(last_chunk)
```

Comment: then I somehow depends on tail binary, though it seems come with all common systems. Is there a better python native way to do this?